# Work around easy-install.pth file

Tags: python-2.7, easy-install, pythonpath

How do I get a python script to import the development version of a module I'm working on (in my home directory) when that module is also defined in a system-wide `easy-install.pth` file?

```
$> more /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/easy-install.pth 
import sys; sys.__plen = len(sys.path)
./foo-1.1.09-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
import sys; new=sys.path[sys.__plen:]; del sys.path[sys.__plen:];      
p=getattr(sys,'__egginsert',0); sys.path[p:p]=new; sys.__egginsert = p+len(new)
```

The `foo` module is setup like this:

```
foo/
   |---- __init__.py
   |---- test.py 
   |---- module1.py
   |---- etc.
```

I want to execute a script from the command line, but When I do

```
/home/dave/src$> python foo/test.py
```

that script imports the version that had been installed under `/usr`; same thing if my working directory is `/home/dave/src/foo`.

Of course, I have `/home/dave/src` at the front of my `PYTHONPATH`.

What is a viable-work around for the way that the `easy-install.pth` gets pre-pended to the `PYTHONPATH`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `-S` option and an fully explicit path.

For example

```
$> PYTHONPATH=$HOME/src:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages python -S foo/test.py
```